# Call/Define Open Dataset to Run Python Calc in SPSS

Tags: python, arcgis, spss, arcpy

I have this ArcGIS python code (using arcpy module) that I need to import and run in SPSS.

The python code works in ArcGIS, and I have been able to successfully set the python library to the ArcGIS x64 python directory.

**My question is this:**  How can I call/define the open (or can be closed) data set that I want to run the calculations on? (My current code defines this in line 2 table "CURRENT_DATABASE_MEMORY")

here is my code that works in ArcGIS/Python.  I have not been able to successfully find a solution to this problem.

```
import arcpy
table = "CURRENT_DATABASE_MEMORY"

valueList = [r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ["FULL_ADDRESS"])]
valueDict = collections.Counter(valueList)
uniqueList = valueDict.keys()
uniqueList.sort() 
updateRows = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, ["FULL_ADDRESS","ALL_LIVE"])
for updateRow in updateRows:
   updateRow[1] = valueDict[updateRow[0]]  
   updateRows.updateRow(updateRow)
del updateRow, updateRows


valueList = [r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ["FULL_ADDRESS_NAME"])]
valueDict = collections.Counter(valueList)
uniqueList = valueDict.keys()
uniqueList.sort() 
updateRows = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, ["FULL_ADDRESS_NAME","ALL_LIVE"])
for updateRow in updateRows:
   updateRow[1] = valueDict[updateRow[0]]  
   updateRows.updateRow(updateRow)
del updateRow, updateRows

uniqueValues = {}
values = []
newID = 0

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, ["FULL_ADDRESS_NAME","FEAT_SEQ"]) as updateRows:
    for row in updateRows:
        nameValue = row[0]
        if nameValue in uniqueValues:
            row[1] = uniqueValues[nameValue]
        else:
            newID += 1
            uniqueValues[nameValue] = newID
            row[1] = newID
        updateRows.updateRow(row)


del row, updateRows
```

Comment: After your series of questions I think the best advice is simply to sit down with the Python programming guide that comes with SPSS. If you can understand what the code is currently doing, you shouldn't have a hard time adapting it to SPSS.

Comment: Grabbing the current SPSS dataset is simple, but there are a few different ways depending on what type of manipulations you want to do. For instance, if you want to make a totally new dataset, you might just grab the current dataset using `alldata = spssdata.Spssdata().fetchall()` and then pipe it to a new dataset using `datasetObj.cases.append(YourResults)`. If you want to add new fields (or new records) in the current dataset though, you would take a different approach.

Comment: IU guesss the method I would prefer would be the on based on performance.  I would like to just run a few complex python calcs (as described above) most likely on the current open dataset.  As I stated below, it just doesn't seem that it is as easy as changing the python directory, and making a few small changes to the old python script is enough t make my old code work in SPSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to what Andy wrote, you might want to consider issuing a command to SPSS using the Submit api to read the dataset via ODBC (assuming that you have a driver for that source), or you could read the datas source directly in the Python code, manipulate it, and then write it to SPSS using the various apis provided for that in the Python plugin.  The best choice will depend on the role that you want SPSS to play in processing this data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  My overall goal is to optimize performance, and minimize the time it takes to run all my python scripts.  I have a huge dataset (millions of records, hundreds of fields).  Currently, I was doing my initial data cleaning in spss, exporting out to a csv, then running the python script in an instance of ArcGIS 10.2 that ran some complex calcs that I was not able (that I know of) to run in SPSS.  The time it took to run all my python scripts was around 23 hours.  By running all my calcs in SPSS I can cut out a few steps which will save a few hours right there.

Comment: So whatever is the best method to optimize performance/save time, It is what I am after.  I thought I understood that by just calling all my arcpy module in this spss instance, I could run all my previously created python scripts.  But alas it seems it is just not that simple!